# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "getTextInputValue") discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need it to output what the person wrote in the modal window. If you remove the

```
const reasonn = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("reason");
```

line, the modal window opens, but when sending, the bot crashes because it did not receive a response.

Error:

```
D:\v144\Events\interactions\Suggestion.js:43
                        const reasonn = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("reason");
                                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTextInputValue')
    at D:\v144\Events\interactions\Suggestion.js:43:60
    at D:\v144\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5267:18
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

Node.js v18.14.1
```

Code:

```js
const { PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, IntegrationApplication, TextInputStyle, TextInputBuilder, ModalBuilder, ActionRowBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const suggestionSchema = require("../../Models/Suggestion");

module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",
    async execute(interaction) {
        const { member, guildId, customId, message } = interaction;

        if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

        if (customId == "suggest-accept" || customId == "suggest-decline") {
            if (!member.permissions.has(PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator))
                return interaction.reply({ content: "No permissions!", ephemeral: true });

            suggestionSchema.findOne({ GuildID: guildId, MessageID: message.id }, async (err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;

                if (!data)
                    return interaction.reply({ content: "No data was found.", ephemeral: true });

                const embed = message.embeds[0];

                if (!embed)
                    return interaction.reply({ content: "No embed was found.", ephemeral: true });

                switch (customId) {
                    case "suggest-accept":
                        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
                        .setTitle('Accept')
                        .setCustomId('modal')

                        const reason = new TextInputBuilder()
                        .setCustomId('reason')
                        .setRequired(true)
                        .setLabel('Reason')
                        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

                        const reasons = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(reason)

                        modal.addComponents(reasons)
                        interaction.showModal(modal)

                        const reasonn = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("reason");

                        embed.data.fields[2] = { name: "Status", value: "Accepted", inline: true };
                        embed.data.fields[3] = { name: "Reason", value: `${reasonn}`, inline: true };
                        const acceptedEmbed = EmbedBuilder.from(embed).setColor("Green");

                        message.edit({ embeds: [acceptedEmbed] });
                        interaction.reply({ content: "Suggestion accepted.", ephemeral: true });
                        break;
                    case "suggest-decline":
                        embed.data.fields[2] = { name: "Status", value: "Declined", inline: true };
                        const declinedEmbed = EmbedBuilder.from(embed).setColor("Red");

                        message.edit({ embeds: [declinedEmbed] });
                        interaction.reply({ content: "Suggestion declined.", ephemeral: true });
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to make it so that when a person clicks on a button, a modal window with a reason pops out. He had to enter it there and the reason was replaced in suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is a typeguard at the top. I'm a big fan of early returns but this `if (!interaction.isButton()) return;` will stop executing any code below it if the `interaction` is not a [`ButtonInteraction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ButtonInteraction). So your code will only work for `ButtonInteraction`s and those don't have a `fields` property, that's why you receive the error.

You will need to check if the `interaction` is a `ModalSubmitInteraction`. That's the one that has the [`fields`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ModalSubmitInteraction?scrollTo=fields) of your modal.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'interactionCreate',
  async execute(interaction) {
    const { member, guildId, customId, message } = interaction;

    if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
      // all code that you want to run after the user submitted the modal
      // interaction.fields.getTextInputValue() is available here
    }

    if (interaction.isButton()) {
      // all code that you want to run after the user clicked a button
      // interaction.fields.getTextInputValue() throws error here
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to send, they tell me "Something went wrong, try again later"

Comment: I don't think I can help you with that without seeing your code and error message. The code snippet you posted doesn't log _"Something went wrong, try again later"_ so it's coming from somewhere else.