TypeError: options.getTextImputValue is not a function
I am trying to create a simple Discord Bot command, where I can create an embed. The problem seems to be in one line, where I want to get description of the embed from a modal. My problem lies somewhere in the line 38, tho I don't know what is exactly wrong. Here's my code:
const {SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle, ActionRowBuilder} = require('discord.js');


module.exports = { 
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('embed-create')
    .setDescription('everything with embeds')
    .addStringOption(option => option.setName('title').setDescription('set the title for the embed').setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option => option.setName('color').setDescription('set color for your embed').setMaxLength(6).setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option => option.setName('thumbnail').setDescription('set thumbnail for your embed').setRequired(false))
    .addStringOption(option => option.setName('image').setDescription('set image for your embed').setRequired(false))
    .addChannelOption(option => option.setName('channel').setDescription('which channel should it be send to').setRequired(false)),


async execute(interaction) {
    const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('creating')
            .setTitle('Nowy Embed')

        const desc = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('a')
            .setLabel("Write Description here")
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)
            .setPlaceholder("ex. sth went to school")

        const secondActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(desc)
        
        modal.addComponents(secondActionRow);
        
        await interaction.showModal(modal);

        await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({ time: 60_000 })
            .then(interaction => 
               interaction.reply({content: "Let's see", ephemeral: true}))
        
        const {options} = interaction;
            const title = options.getString('title');
            const description = options.fields.getTextInputValue('a');
            const color = options.getString('color');
            const thumbnail = options.getString('thumbnail');
            const image = options.getString('image');
            const {channel} = options.get('channel');
            
            if (image){
               if (!image.startsWith('https')) { 
               await interaction.followUp({content:"Your image cannot be used! Use a link starting with http.", ephemeral: true})
                return}
            
            };
            
            if (thumbnail){
               if (!thumbnail.startsWith('https')) {
               await interaction.followUp ({content:"Your thumbnail cannot be used! Use a link starting with http.", ephemeral: true})
               return}
            };
            
            const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
             .setTitle(title)
             .setDescription(description)
             .setColor(`#${color}`)
             .setThumbnail(thumbnail)
             .setImage(image)

        await interaction.followUp ({content:"Your embed has been send below", ephemeral:(true)});
        await channel.send({ embeds:[embed] })

 }
}

Also, the cmd warns me with this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTextInputValue')
    at Object.execute (bot\commands\utility\create.js:46:41)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (bot\index.js:42:3)

As I worked on it for a while, I tried seeking about this problem and changed the code in various ways. I tried adding to te line
const description = options.getTextInputValue('a');

the options.fields.getTextInputValue but with no effect. Cmd even sent me, that it doesn't recognize it as a command. I haven't seen anyone encounter the same problem, so I need to ask about it myself.
I am currently working on vscode, node.js v20.16.0 and Discord.js v14.15.3.

Are you sure it shouldn't be getTextInputValue ?

@AHaworth I didn't mean, that t shouldn't be it. It's just that it somehow doesn't work the way I have it written. Mostly I get the problem, that it is not a function, or that it is undefined.

Sorry, I don't fully understand your comment. My point was that in your title and in the given code and in the text you have getTextimputValue and I would have thought you meant getTextInputValue (i.e. an n instead of the m).

@AHaworth Ah, it seems I've made a typo. But event tho I changed it now, it still has a problem:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTextInputValue'), still, thank you for finding the typo, as I am not a native English speaker and I do make some mistakes like this sometimes.

The interaction where you get the options from is a ChatInputCommandInteraction, not a ModalSubmitInteraction, so it won't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75522191/6126373 getTextInputValue('a') will be available inside that awaitModalSubmit only (or once it's resolved). You shouldn't use that then() if you already use async-await. Something like this should work better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75941826/6126373

@ZsoltMeszaros Oh my god, thank you so much! It does work now, that I've changed the code in somewhat that way. I will continue to work on it tho, because that is the result I wanted, but it also has a problem, if I don't give it links for image or thumbnail. But I will probably figure it out myself. Thank you for the time and the help I needed.
